# Solving complex second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I have this equation:

$$\Omega \frac{d}{dt}v_x - \frac{d^2}{dz^2}v_x = 0$$ And I am finding a solution in a form of:

$$v_x = A(x,y,z) e^{it} $$ where $A(x,y,z$ is a complex amplitude. After simple substitution I am getting:

$$ A''-i\Omega A. $$ And here I stumbled. I know that oscillator equation has the form of: $A''+ \omega_0^2A=0$, but in that case $\omega_0$ is a real number, whereas in my case if I, for example, substitute $\omega_0^2=-i\Omega$ I will get the same equation where $\omega_0$ is a complex number.. So if I do this than I can write a solution in the following form:

$$A = C_1e^{i\omega_0z} + C_2e^{-i\omega_0z}$$ is it eligible or not?

I know from physical view that $v_x$ has to have a periodic solution *(I know it from physical statement of my problem)* so it correlates with physical sence. Exponent is responsible for periodic time in the system while Amplitude also has periodic behaviour.

But I am confused: $C_1 $ and $C_2 $ are the complex amplitude? Because if I try to reformulate the problem to its initial values like: $\omega_0 = \sqrt{-i\Omega}$ than after proccessing the result will be: $\omega_0 = \sqrt{\Omega}\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{i} = - 0.7 \sqrt{\Omega} + 0.7 \sqrt{\Omega} i$ and after substituting this to :

$$A = C_3e^{-z}e^{-0.7i\sqrt{\Omega}z} + C_4e^{z}e^{0.7i\sqrt{\Omega}z}$$ which is not periodical solution anymore.. I am so confused here.. How should I tackle this problem..

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT ONE**

Of course, since $v_x(x, y, z, t)$, but one has to differentiate over $z$ and $t$ . It gets dependency from $z$ in explicit form and dependency from $x, y$ goes to 'constants', dependency from $t$ vanishes since we find solution that already includes $t$ in exponent and

$$A = C_1(x, y)e^{i\omega_0z} + C_2(x, y)e^{-i\omega_0z}$$

Comment: Are those supposed to be partial derivatives?

Comment: @K.defaoite Please , see Edit One

Comment: I looked at your edit but I still don’t understand why the derivatives aren’t written as partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $x,y,z$ are NOT function of $t$ because this is not specified in the wording of the question.

$$\Omega \frac{\partial v_x}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial^2 v_x}{\partial z^2} = 0$$ 
As far as I can understand you are looking for a solution on the form :

$$v_x = A(x,y,z) e^{it}\quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial v_x}{\partial t}=i A(x,y,z) e^{it} \\
\frac{\partial^2 v_x}{\partial z^2}=\frac{\partial^2 A(x,y,z)}{\partial z^2}e^{it}
\end{cases}$$
$$\Omega i A(x,y,z) e^{it} - \frac{\partial^2 A(x,y,z)}{\partial z^2}e^{it} = 0$$ 
$$i\Omega A(x,y,z)  - \frac{\partial^2 A(x,y,z)}{\partial z^2} = 0$$ 
Since there is no partial derivatives with regards to $x$ and $y$ the PDE is reduced to an ODE with regard to the variable $z$ only. $x,y$ must be considered as parameters.
$$i\Omega A-A''=0$$
$$A(x,y,z)=c_1(x,y)\exp\left(\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2\Omega}}z\right)+c_2(x,y)\exp\left(-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2\Omega}}z\right)$$
Of course $c_1(x,y)$ and $c_2(x,y)$ can be complex.

One can separate the sinusoidal terms as :
$$\exp\left(\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2\Omega}}z\right)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\Omega}}z\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\Omega}}z\right) -i\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\Omega}}z\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\Omega}}z\right) $$

Finally $v_x(x,y,z,t)$ is obtained with arbitrary functions $c_1(x,y)$ and $c_2(x,y)$ into it.

The integration with respect to $x$ leads to $v(x,y,z,t)$ with $c_1$ replaced by $C_1(x,y)=\int c_1(x,y)dx+f_1(y)$ and $c_2$ replaced by $C_2(x,y)=\int c_2(x,y)dx+f_2(y)$. All are arbitrary complex and/or real functions.